# Capture a STD::unique_loc<std::mutex> in a lambda function which is used as a thread function

Tags: c++, c++11, stdthread, unique-lock

Is there any potential problem if capturing a `STD::unique_loc<std::mutex>` in a lambda function which is used as a thread function?
e.g:

```
int foo()
{
    std::mutex mtxRunOver;
    std::unique_lock <std::mutex> ulkRunOver(mtxRunOver);
    std::thread workThread([&](){
        workThread.detach();
        do_some_process_for_seconds();
        }
    );

    do_some_work();
}
```

Comment: Your lambda is not capturing the lock. And even if it did, capturing a lock by reference is pointless since it does not extend the objects lifetime. If the thread needs to holds the mutex until it's done you need to lock the mutex inside the lambda. Also, detatching a thread is usually not a good idea.

Comment: @super Thank you for your clarification. Why capturing a lock by reference could not extend the object's lifetime? Could you please explain that in more detail? And the capture clause is `&`, I think all the variables have been captured.

Comment: `&` makes the default capture mode by reference. The lambda still only captures the variables that it actually uses. And I can't really explain objects and their lifetime in comments here. Go read a good book or find a good tutorial. Scope and life-time are very important fundamental concepts.